Vue application served by vite is not loading environment variables from .env files located at the root of the project, backend is rails-api
My vue application is not loading environment variables properly.
I have the dotenv library in package.json.
.env.development has VITE_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
and one of my pinia files uses the VITE_BACKEND_URL environment variable. I added a console.log in the file to check the content of the variable.
const BACKEND_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL
console.log('BACKEND_URL 1', BACKEND_URL)

the console.log returns BACKEND_URL 1 undefined.
I started my rails server with RAILS_ENV=development rails s.

My application is a headless project. I have a frontend folder at the root level of my application. The .env files have to be located at the root of the frontend folder, not the root of the whole project.
